# Performance problems on RDC to our Terminal-Server Win2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rdp, terminal-server

we have a new win2008-R2 (2x Xeon X5570, 32GB RAM).

There I have installed the terminal-server roles, thats all OK.

Currently 5 users are working at this server, but all get a very low performance in their remote-desktop session.
Sometime it takes 1-2 seconds till the keyboard-inputs will be performed and shown.

At the clients I run RDP v 6.1

We have also an older TS-server (based on Win2003 with an Opteron-CPU), there are working about 20 users at the same time. There I do not have the troubles with the inputs at the remote-desktop sessions.

Both servers are connected to the same gigabit-switch.

Any ideas what could cause the troubles at the Win2008 R2?

Many thanks in advance.

Regards

Chris

Answer (score 1):

[Preformance monitor](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Windows_2003_Performance_Monitor.html)

I would make preformance counter for
CPU usage
CPU Que
Network Que
Disk Que

See if any of those have high values, with your hardware something is wrong. But first you must narrow down what is wrong